# what does it mean when WriteProcessMemory returns 487 ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS?

Tags: c++, windows

it gives a very short description on the msdn website saying "Attempt to access invalid address." I'm just not sure if it means invalid as in "this is not even an address" or as in "you can't use this address! "

since im not sure which one it is, it's very difficult to decide what to try next.

my call to WriteProcessMemory:

```
if(!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)loc.c_str(), (LPVOID)"Book of Stupid", sizeof("Book of Stupid"), NULL))
{
std::cout << "writefail to " + loc + "\nerror ";
std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
```

thank you for your time

Comment: Using `sizeof("Book of Stupid")` is terribly wrong to begin with, as it gives you the size of a pointer (typically 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your system), and not the length of your string as you're probably expecting...

Comment: It means what it says, the address is not valid.  The odds that the address of *loc* in your process is also valid in another process are pretty low.  The odds that it is a valid address and does what you hope it does are -100%

Comment: @barakmanos: actually, no, `sizeof("constant string")` gives you the length in bytes of the string, including the terminator.  (Or, at least, that's what it does in MSVC.  I imagine it's in the standard, but I don't know for certain.)

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says, this address cannot be modified. Your function call looks wrong:

```
(LPVOID)loc.c_str()
```

this looks like a local std::string, so you are trying to modify local address (from your own app), in some other app hProcess? That will certainly fail.

Going further, assuming that hProcess is for current process, then you would have to ensure that loc is actually long enought to be modified.